# Invalid anonymous type member declarator - Anonymous type + Nullable operator

Tags: c#, linq

I need to find duplicate email addresses that are located within a method call of a collection of objects.

What is the correct syntax for GroupBy in this case?

```
// PsuedoCode

Person
{
   List<string> GetEmails();
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int Identity {get;set;}
} 

List<Person> People = GetPeopleFromDatabase();

var  duplicateEmail =   
     people.GroupBy(x =>  x.GetEmails()??????? )
      .Where(g=> g.Count() > 1) 
      .Select(y => y)
      .ToList();
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to get the original list of duplicate person objects so I can work with those keys directly.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flatten the list of emails first, then group.

```
var query =
    from p in people
    from e in p.GetEmails()
    group p by e into g
    where g.Count() > 1
    select g;
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you say they linq language style you used is more versatile than the extension methods I used?

Comment: Each syntax has its uses.  Personally, I generally stick to the query syntax wherever possible, then use extensions as needed.  This query can be expressed purely in the query syntax.

Comment: Now you need a person that speaks that SQL-like syntax to understand it. In the other case you just need a developer that speaks any language that supports methods and lambdas

Comment: @RoyalBg: I don't look at it that way. It's C#, that happens to have a syntax that is similar to what is used in another language. It's been in the language for years, you're limiting yourself as a developer if you can not/will not learn what other things the language has to offer to you.  You don't necessarily need to use it in your everyday code, but you cannot treat it as witchcraft. It's not much different from the extension syntax anyway. Once you understand the translation between the two, it should be a non-issue.

Comment: Is there any, except the syntax? What would be the difference, if I use selected many instead nested query?

Comment: For this specific case, there would be little difference, the compiler will generate the same or similar query.  There are things in the query syntax that you just cannot express nicely in the extension syntax. The [let clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) is just one of those constructs that has no direct translation.  Joins and group joins also tend do complicate things in the extension syntax. It all boils down to what is more readable in the end. You just need to learn the language to fully appreciate what is really readable.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with @JeffMercado, IMHO it's simpler and more readable using query syntax. Anyway here it is a solution using method syntax:

```
var query = people.SelectMany(p=> p.GetEmails(), (person, email) => new { person, email})
                  .GroupBy(e=>e.email, e=>e.person)
                  .Where(g=>g.Count()>1);
```

The key to flatten the list of emails is the [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer Jeff Mercado has provided, I would sugest you to return a list of strings with only duplicated e-mails.
It would be something like this:

```
var query =
    (from p in people
     from e in p.GetEmails()
     group p by e into g
     where g.Count() > 1
     select g).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

I hope it helps you!